# How to extract value of class of bytes enum using string name in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, enums

I have the following code

```
class LogLevels:
    level_0 = b"0"
    level_1 = b"1"
    level_2 = b"2"
    level_3 = b"3"
    level_4 = b"4"
    level_5 = b"5"
    level_6 = b"6"
    level_7 = b"7"
    level_8 = b"8"


non_default_log_levels = ("level_4", "level_5", "level_6")

for log_level in non_default_log_levels:
    print(log_level)
    print(LogLevels[log_level])
```

**I need to find a way to extract the value of each enum using the string name.**

Expected result:

```
level_4
b"4"
level_5
b"5"
level_6
b"6"
```

Comment: Please edit into your question the _full text_ of the error message from your current code, __as text__

Comment: Note that `LogLevels` is not an `Enum` -- if it were, you could do `LogLevels[log_level]` to get the enum member, and `LogLevels[log_level].value` to get the value.

Comment: Wow. @EthanFurman in person! I should request an autograph.

Comment: @jsbueno: *ethan furman* :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python's objects do not allow attribute access directly by theirs string names exactly due to the undestanding that *data* should be treated as data, and code be fixed by default. So, in this it differs from Javascript, for example. However, one of the great strenghts is that variable, methods and attributes name can be easily introspected with a single indirection - unlike static languages that hold this separation between data and code too strictly. In this case, the only indirection needed is use the built-in `getattr` function to get the class attributes by name:

```
for log_level in non_default_log_levels:
    print(log_level)
    print(getattr(LogLevels, log_level))
```

I'd end this suggesting that you check [Python Enums](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html)  for this use case - it looks like they will fit your needs nicely.

Comment: This dosn’t feel like very nice code to expose a Python beginner to. Can you explain how it works and why this a good answer? Are there hints of better ways?

Comment: yes. i was writing these as you post the comment.

Comment: Thank you so much.
This perfectly answer the question